# Regex matching multiple words from the LIST

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, matcher

Writing Regex that matches the set item list? for an example, write regex that matches whatever is in the targetValues ?

Apex code:

```
String result = 'favorable day can one introduced two sentiments four entreaties. three Noisier carried of in warrant because '; //some random text

Set<String> targetValues = new Set<String>{'one', 'two', 'three'};

boolean foundme = false;
for (String s : targetValues) {
       if (result.containsIgnoreCase(s)) {
          foundme = true;
       }
}
```

The above code works if it matches at least one item list but I like to have it match `all` that is exists in the `targetValues` otherwise returns false.

Comment: whoever vote to close, care to explain WHY ?

Comment: Looks like you haven't really tried or researched into writing one yourself. Additionally, Regex's are generic programming, not necessarily related to Salesforce (even  if it is in the 'context' of Salesforce). This type of question would be best suited on stackoverflow.com imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just remove elements from the set as you find matches, and check if the set is empty at the end.

```
for (String targetValue : targetValues)
    if (result.containsIgnoreCase(targetValue))
        targetValues.remove(targetValue);
Boolean matchesAll = !targetValues.isEmpty();
```

Comment: If you want to find multiple terms independent of ordering, the expression syntax gets pretty tricky.

Comment: Or a second Set that's a copy, in case you don't want to unexpectedly modify the original set (Apex's pass by reference could cause issues).

Comment: Yeah addition of a second set would be a simple and obvious change given certain contexts, probably does bear editing in though.

Answer (score 2):

As a regular expression, you could do this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?i)(one|two|three)');
Set<String> expected = new Set<String>{'one','two','three'};
Set<String> matches = new Set<String>();
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
while(m.find()) {
  matches.add(m.group(0).toLowerCase());
}
if(matches == expected) {
  // All matches were found //
}
```